# Poblar ArrayList con objetos y mostrar

Tags: java

Me piden que cree dos listas como variables globales, estas listas se componen de objetos.

Una listare presenta el color (es decir 1 = rojo, 2 = verde, 3= amarillo), esta lista tiene el campo `id` y `codigo` y la otra comparte el mismo campo `id` y tiene otro campo llamado `stock`.

El proceso datos se encargara de poblar esas listas.

Tengo que mostrar los id de los colores seleccionados siempre que exista alguna cantidad de este.

Esto me muestra códigos que no tienen sentido, algo asi como @2312344 y solo quiero que muestre una cifra.

```
public class prueba {

    public int Id;
    public int cantidad;

    public prueba(int id) {
        super();
        Id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

}
```

```
public class producto {

    public int Id;
    public int codigo;

    public producto(int id, int codigo) {
        super();
        Id = id;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

}
```

```
public class sistema {

    public static List<prueba> pr = new ArrayList<prueba>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prueba pru = new prueba(0); 
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

                pr.add(new prueba(i)); 
            }
        System.out.print(prueba);

    }
}
```

Comment: Te imprime eso porque en ningún momento sobrescribes el método `toString()` en la clase `Prueba`.

Comment: Te en cuenta que esta línea de código: `System.out.print(prueba);` es equivalente a `System.out.print(prueba.toString());`
`

Comment: Veo que utilizas "super()" sin embargo, no veo el constructor padre al que hace referencia ya que en ninguna parte veo que aplicas herencia

Comment: Asi mismo, la linea de codigo "Prueba pru = new Prueba(0)" no tiene funcionalidad alguna

Answer (score 2):

Déjame hacerte algunos comentarios respecto a tu código:

- Las llamadas a super() que hay en los constructores no tienen ningún
  sentido, puesto que ninguna de esas dos clases extiende a otras.
  Recuerda que la llamada a super() en un constructor sirve para llamar
  al constructor de la clase madre.
- Si las variables miembro de esas clases son públicas, no tiene sentido que haya 
  setters y getters. Existe una norma que indica que se deben declarar
  privadas. Pero si sólo estás usando eso para hacer pruebas, entonces
  los setters y los getters sobran, siendo variables miembro públicas.
- Y finalmente, en el programa principal, date cuenta que la lista pr
  no tiene ninguna repercusión. De hecho, la variable pru no se usa en
  el bucle. Es decir, la última linea podría ser simplemente

  System.out.print(new prueba(0));

En general, no se entiende exactamente que quieres hacer. Y por supuesto que MrDave1999 tiene razón: Sobreescribe el método toString() en la clase prueba

```
public class prueba {

// ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + Id;
    }
}
```

para definir qué es lo que quieres que se escriba cuando se pida escribir un objeto de la clase prueba.

Y ya te digo, por lo demás, no entiendo el problema.

Comment: 1) En java todas las clases heredan de alguna otra. Si no se define explícitamente heredará de `Object`. 2) Dicho lo anterior tampoco es incorrecto, aunque si redundante, hacer la llamada `super()` en el constructor de las clase. De hecho el compilador la agrega por tí si no lo haces ya que es un requerimiento del lenguaje que todas las subclases llamen en su constructor primero a un constructor del padre.

Comment: 1) Precisamente, como es bien sabido que todas heredan de Object, se dice que no heredan cuando no lo hacen explícitamente. 2) En programación, lo redundante es incorrecto. De hecho, que lo haga el compilador significa que no lo tienes que hacer tu, por legibilidad, y por higiene del código.

Comment: 1) Solo si nos alejamos de una explicación técnicamente correcta. 2) Que evitar este tipo de redundancia nos permita tener un código más legible y limpio no lo hace incorrecto. En este caso preferiría decir que es innecesario y explicaría los motivos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo unas anotaciones:

1. Como mencionó el compañero arriba, las llamadas super() no tienen sentido debido a que ninguna clase hereda algo de la otra.
2. Lo que te muestra al correr el codigo es el espacio en memoria donde se encuentra ese dato que estas buscando, más no el dato. y eso pasa por una simple razón:
       ***- Te falta el toString() en la clase prueba.***
3. La linea donde declaras e instancias un objeto Prueba llamado "pru" no se está utilizando en ninguna parte del main.
4. Debes tener en cuenta que los getter y setter se utilizan cuando tus atributos son privados, y en tu codigo tanto en la clase Prueba como en la clase Producto, tus atributos son publicos

Teniendo en cuenta las anotaciones, una manera de que funcione tu código sería la siguiente:

```
package sof;

public class Prueba {
    private int Id;          // ambos atributos privados para hacer uso de los getter
    private int cantidad;    // y setter 

    public Prueba(int id, int cant) {   // constructor sin el llamado "super()"
       this.Id = id;
       this.cantidad = cant;
    }

    public int getId() {
       return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
       this.Id = Id;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
       return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
       this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    @Override   // con este override controlas la manera en que se imprime la lista
    public String toString() {
       return "Prueba{" + "Id=" + Id + ", cantidad=" + cantidad + '}';
    }

}
```

y el main se vería así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Prueba> pr = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++){
        pr.add(new Prueba(i, i+1));   // aqui se pobla la lista con sus dos parametros
    }                                 // corresp. ID y Cantidad  

    for(Prueba p : pr){         // impresión de la lista con el foreach que hace uso
        System.out.println(p);  // del toString de la clase en cuestión
    }

    // Tambien puedes imprimir la lista sin usar ningún for sino simplemente así:
    System.out.println(pr.toString());  // pero lo imprime uno al lado de otro y no es 
                                        // visualmente llamativo
}
```

el output que recibirias sería el siguiente: (usando el foreach)

```
Prueba{Id=0, cantidad=1}
Prueba{Id=1, cantidad=2}
Prueba{Id=2, cantidad=3}
Prueba{Id=3, cantidad=4}
Prueba{Id=4, cantidad=5}
```

Comment: *Lo que te muestra al correr el codigo es el espacio en memoria donde se encuentra ese dato que estas buscando, ...* El espacio de memoria es la **celda** donde está justamente el dato en la RAM y lo que muestra en pantalla tampoco sería una dirección de memoria. Simplemente es el valor que retorna el método `toString()` de la clase `Object`..

Comment: Ahh listo, lo demás si comprendiste lo que te quise dar a entender?

Comment: En Java todas las clases heredan de otra. El uso del `super()` no es incorrecto, solo redundante, puesto que el compilador lo agrega por tí.

Comment: pero debes tener en cuenta que el uso del super() en este caso el compañero quería heredar la implementación de la clase Producto donde se recibian dos paramétros. Y al querer hacer eso sin que ninguna de las clases extienda a la otra, si se estará aplicando de manera incorrecta el llamado super()

Comment: Yo no veo en el código que comparte el OP nada que me haga plantearme lo que comentas.